# Sorting Multi-indexed Large Database Table in Sqlite

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, sqlite, gtfs

I am attempting to **select from** (with a `WHERE` clause) **and sort** a large database table in sqlite3 via python.  The sort is currently taking 30+ minutes on about 36 MB of data.  I have a feeling it can work faster than this with indices, but **I think the order of my code may be incorrect**.

The code is executed in the order listed here.

1. My `CREATE TABLE` statement looks like this:

   ```
   c.execute('''CREATE table gtfs_stop_times (
     trip_id text , --REFERENCES gtfs_trips(trip_id),
     arrival_time text, -- CHECK (arrival_time LIKE '__:__:__'),
     departure_time text, -- CHECK (departure_time LIKE '__:__:__'),
     stop_id text , --REFERENCES gtfs_stops(stop_id),
     stop_sequence int NOT NULL --NOT NULL
   )''')
   ```
2. The rows are then inserted in the next step:

   ```
   stop_times = csv.reader(open("tmp\\avl_stop_times.txt"))
   c.executemany('INSERT INTO gtfs_stop_times VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', stop_times)
   ```
3. Next, I create an index out of two columns (`trip_id` and `stop_sequence`):

   ```
   c.execute('CREATE INDEX trip_seq ON gtfs_stop_times (trip_id, stop_sequence)')
   ```
4. Finally, I run a `SELECT` statement with a `WHERE` clause that sorts this data by the two columns used in the index and then write that to a csv file:

   ```
   c.execute('''SELECT gtfs_stop_times.trip_id, gtfs_stop_times.arrival_time, gtfs_stop_times.departure_time, gtfs_stops.stop_id, gtfs_stop_times.stop_sequence
   FROM gtfs_stop_times, gtfs_stops
   WHERE gtfs_stop_times.stop_id=gtfs_stops.stop_code
   ORDER BY gtfs_stop_times.trip_id, gtfs_stop_times.stop_sequence;
   )''')

   f = open("gtfs_update\\stop_times.txt", "w")
   writer = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel')
   writer.writerow([i[0] for i in c.description]) # write headers
   writer.writerows(c)
   del writer
   ```

Is there any way to speed up Step 4 (possibly be changing how I add and/or use the index) or should I just go to lunch while this runs?

I have added PRAGMA statements to try to improve performance to no avail:

```
c.execute('PRAGMA main.page_size = 4096')
c.execute('PRAGMA main.cache_size=10000')
c.execute('PRAGMA main.locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE')
c.execute('PRAGMA main.synchronous=NORMAL')
c.execute('PRAGMA main.journal_mode=WAL')
c.execute('PRAGMA main.cache_size=5000')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECT` executes extremely fast because there is no `gtfs_stops` table and you get nothing but an error message.

If we assume that there is a `gtfs_stops` table, then your `trip_seq` index is already quite optimal for the query.
However, you also need an index for looking up `stop_code` values in the `gtfs_stops` column.

Comment: There is a `gtfs_stops` table.  Sorry that I forgot to mention that.  I'll give the index on `stop_code` a try.

Comment: Really helpful, thanks!  I also added another index for `stop_id` in `gtfs_stop_times`.  Total run time is less than a minute now.  I think I've learned my lesson on the value of indices now.

Comment: Check with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) whether that index is actually used.